# Mysql Custom sorting using Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

i have this sql code

```
"SELECT * FROM t_one order by
                                    (
                                    case t_one.status
                                      when 'valid'   then 1
                                      when 'invalid' then 2
                                      when 'aborted'   then 3
                                      when 'cancel'  then 4
                                      else 9999
                                    end
                                    )";
```

How can i convert this to zend db model functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/SQL-Case-statement-in-Zend-Framework-td656393.html